# Passing perameters between webpages

Tags: web-applications

I'm looking to create a webpage that will pass search strings to another webpage. The target page is not a site or page I created. How can I do this, would it be best using GET or POST?  Would really appreciate the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the target page is not a site that you created then you have to find out which HTTP methods  (GET, POST, PUT) accepts this page or endpoint. In RESTful services, normally to retrieve the standard is to use GET while POST is usually used to create objects.

Comment: How can I find this out?

Comment: The website or web service should provide documentation about it. Otherwise, if is just a web just a "search" button, you can inspect the requests that is using with you click that button, with your browser using "Developer Tools", for example.

Answer (score 0):

see http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp for a full POST vs GET comparison

[image]